# how to do social media integration with all share options that are available on mobile in android?somebody help me

Tags: android

how to do social media integration with all share options that are available on mobile in android?
This feature is available with phonegap 3.0 , I want do the same in android app...somebody help

Comment: Create a intent with the content type plain/text. That should not be too hard to Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Intent with ACTION_SEND. Please refer below code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.setType("image/*");
 Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg"));
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share Via");
```

Comment: Thanks alot ...its working well..I want to post URL with content..help me

Comment: from my App I want to share content which is in aarti_specific.get(0)(ArrayList)

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.url.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));

Comment: instead of image type please use
sendingIntent.setType("text/plain") and sendingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

Comment: Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, x);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share Via"));

Comment: I try to post like above..but in facebook that was not posted